# How should I style my h1 headers with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I started to use the jQuery UI. I already use some widgets and these work fine. I have many pages in my web site that look like this:

```
<div id="bdy" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<div class="bdy_box">
<h1>Home</h1
```

The first two lines come from a master layout **but** the third line is a user generated page. So what I have is a large number of user generated pages that use headers like `<h1>` etc.

How should I style these? My users use tinymce to do the headers and they only know that a header should be something enclosed in h1. I can't really ask them to start enclosing the headers also in ui-widget-header.

I want them to use the jQuery UI theme but can't ask my users to change all of the pages where they put h1. I also want to use themeroller so I somehow want to have the headers change color when needed.

Comment: Why not just update your site's stylesheets? That's what CSS is for, using jQuery to solve basic stylings is like using a sledgehammer to Kill a fly.  It's overkill and very bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I dont really follow, but can you insert a script into each page?

something like the following

`$('h1').wrap('<div id="bdy" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">');`

http://jsfiddle.net/FpHvy/

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of doing that. Do you have any headers on your style that use style with jQuery? I would like to make my header look something like the datepicker header. I just am not sure where to start.